# MPDF - Iniciar paginação com numeração vinda de variável

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

Tenho uma aplicação e preciso imprimir um documento usando a classe [mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf), no entanto, preciso que o número da ***paginação*** se inicie, por exemplo a partir do número **43**, **44**, **45** e assim por diante e não a partir do **1**, **2**, **3**, como é o seu padrão. Gostaria que a paginação começasse a partir de uma variável `$numero_inicial`. Eu consegui começar a partir de qualquer número, mas apenas pulando uma folha através do `pagebreak` e `resetnumpage`, porém não posso pular uma página e deixar uma folha em branco.

Abaixo está o meu código.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();    
$mpdf->setFooter("{PAGENO}");    
$numero_paginas = "{nb}";    
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="img/cabecalho.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>');    
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('');    
$mpdf->WriteHTML('    
<style type="text/css">
body{
    font-family:Arial, Times New Roman, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
}
</style>' . $corpo_documento . '');    
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicione 2 linhas:

```
$numero_inicial = 43;
$mpdf->AddPage('', '', $numero_inicial);
```

onde a valor da variável `$numero_inicial` seria o ***inicio*** da sua paginação.

***Código completo:***

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$numero_inicial = 43;
$mpdf->AddPage('', '', $numero_inicial); // definindo o número que inicia a página
$mpdf->setFooter("{PAGENO}");    
$numero_paginas = "{nb}";    
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="img/cabecalho.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>');    
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('');    
$mpdf->WriteHTML('    
<style type="text/css">
body{
    font-family:Arial, Times New Roman, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
}
</style>'.$corpo_documento.'');    
$mpdf->Output();
exit();
```

***Referencias:***

- [Page numbering](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-numbering.html)
- [Manual - mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/)